# Screen doesn't reload (axios retrigger) when it comes back in view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

In my screen, I load in a list of groups via Axios (using Axios Hooks). However, when I come back to the screen at a later point - I observe that the data doesnt reload (and misses new data from the server).

I assume this is due to the component lifecycle but I have tried different things and cannot force useAxios to trigger each time that the screen comes into view for the user.

My simple screen is here:

```
import * as React from "react";
import useAxios from "axios-hooks";

import { Button, View, Text, TextField } from "react-native-ui-lib";

export default function GroupListScreen({ navigation }: any) {
  const [{ data: groups, loading, error }, refetch] = useAxios(
    "/group_members/"
  );

  if (error) return <Text>Error...</Text>;
  if (loading) return <Text>Loading...</Text>;

  const list = () => {
    return groups.map((group: any) => {
      return (
        <View key={group.id}>
          <Button
            margin-5
            label={group.group.name}
            enableShadow
            onPress={() =>
              navigation.push("Group Overview", { id: group.group.id })
            }
          />
        </View>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <View flex top padding-20 marginT-40>
      <Button
        margin-5
        label="Back"
        enableShadow
        onPress={() => navigation.pop()}
      />
      <Button
        margin-5
        label="Refetch"
        enableShadow
        onPress={() => refetch()}
        disabled={loading}
      />
      {list()}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe  `useEffect(()=>refetch())` without any dependency should work out inthis case, and call `refetch()` inside. Make it like `componentDidMount()`. You can also skip the first time with a custom state. I assume you are talking about when you navigate your route back after first render.

Comment: Then you should check your current group data with incoming data to determine the refetch() behavior inside the useEffect hook. If they are the same, stop calling refetch() or simply return, if different set the new data. Just make a local copy, rendering based on the local copy so you don't run into infinite loop. I doubt that axioshook does not have a shortcut function for this problem. It seems like a common issue.